# Access by id from the component controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access the value of fileInput, textInput from the component controller without using ng-model. But I am getting undefined.

```
<form name="uploadForm">
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" class="ng-hide">
    <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
        <input id="textInput" type="text" placeholder="No file chosen" ng-readonly="true" required current-dir="$ctrl.currentDir">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-raised md-primary">Choose file</md-button>
    <md-button id="saveButton" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.uploadVideoFile($event)" >Upload</md-button>
</div>
</form>



    var input = $(element[0].querySelector('#fileInput'));
    var button = $(element[0].querySelector('#uploadButton'));
    var textInput = $(element[0].querySelector('#textInput'));
```

Comment: have you tried with angular.element() ?

Comment: Yes I did. I am trying to get it without using ng-model

Comment: ?? .. you don't need ng-model .. just try somehting like°: var input = angular.element('#fileInput'));

Comment: I have only jqLite : Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var input = angular.element('#fileInput');
```